# c++ How do I access atomic non-POD member variables?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, atomic

I have a class

```
class connection
{
private:
  static std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<std::queue<buffer<char> > > > queue_;
  std::thread serviceThread_;
  std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> notEmpty_;
  int fileDesc_;

public:
  connection(std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> notEmpty,
             int fileDesc):
    serviceThread_(), notEmpty_(notEmpty), fileDesc_(fileDesc)
  {
    serviceThread_ = std::thread(&connection::service, this);
  }

  void service();

  void join(){ serviceThread_.join(); }
};
```

In `connection::service()` I call `queue_.pop()` or `queue_->pop()` trying to get what I think should be the top of the queue.

When I call `queue_.pop()` I get the error:

```
server/connection.hpp: In member function ‘void connection::service()’:
server/connection.hpp:78:29: error: ‘struct         
std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<std::queue<buffer<char> > > >’ has no member named 
‘pop’ 
queue_.pop();"
```

Fair enough since its an atomic shared pointer.
If I call `queue_->pop()` I get the following error:

```
server/connection.hpp: In member function ‘void connection::service()’:
server/connection.hpp:78:28: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type    
‘std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<std::queue<buffer<char> > > >’
queue_->pop();"
```

I have two questions.

1. How do I call the queue member function which are in the atomic shared pointer?
2. Is there some debugging stuff that shows the member variables of an object? To give me a better idea of what I'm actually trying to play with.

Comment: Perhaps `queue_.load()->pop()`.

Comment: Nice Sahu. So, is that how you have to use atomics to access non-POD types? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: I have never used `std::atomic`. I looked up the documentation and that sounded like the right thing to do. Not sure whether that is the way for the POD types also.

Comment: Does your code compile otherwise? From §29.5/1, `atomic<T>` requires `T` to be trivially copyable. A `shared_ptr` definitely doesn't meet that criterion.

Comment: why you need to wrap `shared_ptr` with `atomic`?? it doesn't work and doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

```
static std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<std::queue<buffer<char> > > > queue_;
```

Big red flag here. `std::atomic` is a magic lock. When you access the `shared_ptr`, it's just a normal `shared_ptr` like any other.

If you need a lock, use `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`. If you don't, then do nothing. In any case, the `std::shared_ptr` should not be decorated.

Also, a global `shared_ptr` to a container is by itself odd. All this buys you is that the `queue` must be explicitly initialized and may be destroyed, so you have created a distinction between an empty queue and a non-existent queue. This looks like gratuitous complexity and overhead, as opposed to a simple global queue.